# Use Object Attribute Input and Output

Tags: animation-nodes

I want to set data on objects, but I have several problems.
Here is one. Why can't 'Object Attribute Input' find the attribute?

[image]

Comment: for custom properties you have to write ["foo"] instead of just foo

Comment: Is that cause you can also get other Attributes?

Comment: yes maybe, normal properties are stored differently and ther has to be a way to differentiate them. You always access custom properties this way from python: object["foo"]

Comment: Could you mark the answer as the correct one to complete this question, please? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use square brackets and quotation marks to make the Object Attribute nodes work with custom properties.

[image]